# how can I refactor this py2neo v4 code to use neo4j 3.4 temporal data types?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm stuck trying to add a date_accepted property to an upload node that represents a scientific paper. Previously, I would have just added a timetree node. However, py2neo v4 no longer supports GregorianCalendar (shame). How would I convert this code snippet to use one of the new temporal data types? I've looked at the docs & online but I'm not yet savvy enough I'm afraid.

```
from datetime import date, datetime # ??? how to use this...

def getAccepted(year_accepted, month, day):
    with open('/home/pmy/pdf/id.txt') as f:
        id = f.read()
        matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)
        upload = matcher.match("Upload", id = id).first()

        a = year_accepted+month+day
        d = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
        # >>> HOW TO CONVERT d TO A TEMPORAL DATA TYPE HERE? <<<            
        try:
            graph.merge(upload)
            upload['accepted_date']=d
            graph.push(upload)

        except IndexError as e:
            print("type error: " + str(e))
        pass
    return 0
```

This works but it pushes the datetime string whereas I want to push a neotime temporal date...

It is possible to insert the datetime variable d above into something like this query below, which also works, but I'm winging this & suspect there's a better way...

```
query='''UNWIND [date({param})] AS date RETURN date'''
result=graph.run(query, param=d).data()
print(result)
```

which returns

```
[{'date': neotime.Date(2010, 10, 23)}]
```

So I could maybe extract the value & push that to the graph? Is this what the developers intended? The Docs are terse and aimed at proper programmers so IDK

Maybe

```
 accepted=result[0].get('date')  # <class 'neotime.Date'>
```

& push that to the graph perhaps?

The py2neo v4 neotime temporal types are very recent & there is not much documentation, or basic tutorials to adapt afaik. Hence this long-winded post. Anyone out there with experience care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Another user posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61989193/13593049

Essentially, you need to use the `neotime` package for your dates and times if you want to use Neo4j data types in your graph. ([Documentation](https://neotime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html))

`neotime` also has functionality to convert `neotime` objects into `datetime` objects.

```py
import neotime

date_accepted = neotime.Date(2020, 05, 25)

print(date_accepted.to_native())
# # datetime.date(2020, 5, 25)
```