# Py2Neo not creating Datetime data type correctly?

Tags: python, datetime, neo4j

I trying build out some functions to populate my new Neo4j graph and I am having a hard time getting dates to populate as the correct data type in Neo4j using Py2Neo v4 and Neo4j 3.4.7. According to the Neo4j [docummention](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/) there are Datetime data types... *and spatial points which I want to get too as well*

I can not for the life of me find any documentation in Py2Neo for using either spatial points or temporal points. I found that there was back in v2 of Py2Neo a plugin for these data types but haven't found anything else on it.

I can send a Python `datetime.datetime` object to Neo4j as a node property but when I try to query with Cypher it doesn't acknowledge it as being in the correct format.

```
# python/py2neo code being used to make the node
example_node = Node("Example", date=datetime.datetime.now())
tx.create(example_node)
```

```
# cypher query
MATCH (e:Example)
WHERE e.date > datetime("2018-12-31")
RETURN e
```

*Note: if I cast `e.date` to `datetime` like this `datetime(e.date)` I get the syntax error:*

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Text cannot be parsed to a DateTime
"2019-01-14 13:00:52"
```

Any help in finding proper documentation in Py2neo, or maybe even a better driver to use would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that `py2neo` uses the `neotime` module under the hood for returning/creating Neo4j date/time types. (Link to documentation [here](https://neotime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) I discovered this by converting an existing string field to a `date` type using Cypher and seeing what `py2neo` returned when I queried the graph.

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node
import neotime
import uuid

# Create graph object
graph = Graph()

# Create example node for a blog post
post = Node(
    'Post', 
    id=str(uuid.uuid4()), 
    title='Neo4j Date Post', 
    text='Here is some text',
    # Use neotime to create Neo4j date/time fields
    timestamp=neotime.DateTime.now(), 
    date=neotime.Date(2020, 5, 23)
)
graph.create(post)
```

Queries on your graph will return `neotime.Date` or `neotime.DateTime` objects, which thankfully have a `to_native()` method you can call, which converts them to `datetime` objects

```py
import neotime

print(neotime.Date(2020, 5, 24).to_native())
# datetime.date(2020, 5, 24)

print(neotime.DateTime.now().to_native())
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 24, 11, 43, 30, 373512)
```

Comment: it seems the code you provided is not working for Neo v5, it marks as `py2neo.database.GraphTransactionError: Invalid transaction` when commiting changes to create a new node

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of `py2neo` neotime does not work anymore
Just use `datetime` and for timezone aware dates incl `pytz`

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node
import time
import datetime
import pytz

g = Graph()
g.run("MATCH(n:DateNode) delete n")
n = Node(
    "DateNode",
    id=12345,
    time_time=time.time(),
    date='date("2019-06-04")',
    datetime_datetime=datetime.datetime(
        year=2019, month=12, day=23, hour=11, minute=49, second=30
    ),
    datetime_date=datetime.date.fromisoformat("2019-12-04"),
    datetime_fromtimestamp=datetime.date.fromtimestamp(time.time()),
    datetime_datetime_now=datetime.datetime.now(),
    datetime_datetime_strptime=datetime.datetime.strptime(
        "December 25, 2010", "%B %d, %Y"
    ),
    datetime_datetime_UTC=datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0, pytz.UTC),
)
g.create(n)

print(
    g.run(
        "MATCH (n:DateNode{id:12345}) WITH n LIMIT 1 UNWIND keys(n) AS key RETURN key, apoc.meta.type(n[key]) as val"
    ).data()
)
```

Results in

```json
[
   {
      "key":"datetime_datetime_UTC",
      "val":"ZonedDateTime"
   },
   {
      "key":"datetime_datetime",
      "val":"LocalDateTime"
   },
   {
      "key":"datetime_datetime_now",
      "val":"LocalDateTime"
   },
   {
      "key":"datetime_datetime_strptime",
      "val":"LocalDateTime"
   },
   {
      "key":"date",
      "val":"STRING"
   },
   {
      "key":"id",
      "val":"INTEGER"
   },
   {
      "key":"time_time",
      "val":"FLOAT"
   },
   {
      "key":"datetime_fromtimestamp",
      "val":"LocalDate"
   },
   {
      "key":"datetime_date",
      "val":"LocalDate"
   }
]
```